# How to relate tables SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables and i want to relate them, but i don't know what im doing wrong. If the way that im thinking is bad, can you correct me also?

I have clients table with Primary key as ID_c column,

```
create table clients
(
  id_c    INTEGER not null,
  name    VARCHAR2(20),
  age     INTEGER,
  address VARCHAR2(20),
  Primary key (id_c)
);
```

also i have products with primary key as ID_p column.

```
create table PRODUCTS
(
  id_p              NUMBER not null,
  name_product      VARCHAR2(30),
  price             NUMBER,
  duration          NUMBER,
  primary key (id_p)
);
```

and now i create third

```
create table TRANSACTIONS
(
  id_t NUMBER not null,
  id_c NUMBER not null,
  id_p NUMBER not null
  primary key (ID_t),
  foreign key (ID_c) references CLIENTS (ID_c),
  foreign key (ID_p) references PRODUCTS (ID_p)
);
```

and now i want to see all records that are connected, so im trying to use that:

```
select * from transactions join clients using (id_c) and join products using (id_p);
```

but only what works is

```
select * from transactions join clients using (id_c);
```

is it relational database or im making something too easy, and too primitive? How can i do that to connect everything?

Comment: `and join` should be just `join`

Comment: what sql is this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the logic, however I would consider columns "firstname" and "lastname" in the clients table and you probably want an additional table "Address" for the client address.

Comment: thanks a_horse_with_no_name, haha i haven't expected that it looks too easy :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select * 
from transactions 
    inner join clients on transactions.id_c = clients.id_c
    inner join products on transactions.id_p = products.id_p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to join?

```
    select * from transactions a 
join clients b on a.id_c = b.id_c
join products c on a.id_p = c.id_p
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join 3 tables, just write:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS t JOIN client c on t.id_c = c.id_c JOIN PRODUCTS p on t.id_p = p.id_p
```